# Neovim gkeep plugin

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim

I installed gkeep plugin for Neovim (https://github.com/stevearc/gkeep.nvim) and didn't like it. I removed it from my plugins (I use vim-plug) and run :PlugClean after that. But now I can't open neovim without error mentioning that gkeep plugin. How to fix this?

```
Error detected while processing function remote#define#request:
line    2:
Error invoking '/home/daniil/dotfiles/nvim/plugged/gkeep.nvim/rplugin/python3/gkeep:autocmd:BufEnter:*'
no request handler registered for "/home/daniil/dotfiles/nvim/plugged/gkeep.nvim/rplugin/python3/gkeep:
```

It's pointing to ~/dotfiles/nvim because I created symbolic link from ~/dotfiles/nvim to ~/.config/nvim.

Also, there is no directory gkeep.nvim inside plugged folder.

UPD: and this is my [plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TRHc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't removed the configuration related to gkeep.nvim. Try to remove all settings related to gkeep.nvim.

Also, when you open neovim, run the command `:UpdateRemotePlugins`. It should solve your issue.

Comment: Oh, I already solved it but forgot to update here. But anyway, thank you.

Comment: @Daniil So what is the real issue that causing the error？

Comment: exactly what you wrote. After I've run `:UpdateRemotePlugins` all worked fine